# two way associative container

Tags: c++, qt, boost, std

I am looking for a data type (or at least a correct name for it) or a map like data structure that allows fast look ups in both directions.

something like:

```
class DoubleMap{
    int getA(int b){
      return b2a[b];
    }
    int getB(int a){
      return a2b[a];
    }

    void insert(int a, int b){
      a2b[a] = b;
      b2a[b] = a;
    }
    std::map<int, int> a2b;
    std::map<int, int> b2a;

};
```

of course templated and more sophisticated.

Is there a name for it and some std container or something from Qt or boost?

Comment: [`bimap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) is probably what you're after

Comment: @EdChum thank you.  may be post this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using a [`boost::bimap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/one_minute_tutorial.html) this is designed for lookups by the key or value.

So in your case you can just do:

```
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
typedef boost::bimap< int, int > bm_type;
bm_type doubleMap;
```

then to perform lookup by key:

```
doubleMap.left.find(key)
```

lookup by value:

```
doubleMap.right.find(val)
```